# How to make, count row result and become a column -MS ACCESS QUERY

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.Name, Customers.Stall_Number, Animal_Types.Code, Count(Animal_Types.Code) AS CountOfCode, Sum(Transaction_Details.Weight) AS TotalWeight
FROM (Customers INNER JOIN Transactions ON Customers.ID = Transactions.Customer) INNER JOIN ((Animal_Types INNER JOIN Carcass ON Animal_Types.ID = Carcass.Animal_Type) INNER JOIN Transaction_Details ON Carcass.ID = Transaction_Details.Carcass) ON Transactions.ID = Transaction_Details.Transaction
GROUP BY Customers.Name, Customers.Stall_Number, Animal_Types.Code;
```

Please refer to images below for more details.

[image: Actual:]
[image: Expected:]

Answer (score 0):

To get rows to become columns, you will need to use a crosstab query:

```sql
TRANSFORM Count(Animal_Types.Code)
SELECT Customers.Name, Customers.Stall_Number, Sum(Transaction_Details.Weight) AS TotalWeight
FROM (Customers INNER JOIN Transactions ON Customers.ID = Transactions.Customer) INNER JOIN ((Animal_Types INNER JOIN Carcass ON Animal_Types.ID = Carcass.Animal_Type) INNER JOIN Transaction_Details ON Carcass.ID = Transaction_Details.Carcass) ON Transactions.ID = Transaction_Details.Transaction
GROUP BY Customers.Name, Customers.Stall_Number, Animal_Types.Code
PIVOT Animal_Types.Code
```